# Send email notification when sidekiq start or stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I need to send email notifications if sidekiq crashes or stops at anytime and also can i send notification when sidekiq start.

It will be really helpful for me if i get notification email.

Answer (score 0):

I use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) for this.  You'll need to run sidekiq as a service first, see init script example here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/sidekiq

A sample monit file for tracking the process would be:

```
check process sidekiq with pidfile /home/deployer/my_app/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/sidekiq start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/sidekiq stop"
if totalmem is greater than 800 MB for 2 cycles then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: Is there any gems to do monitoring for sidekiq.

Comment: There are lots of gems for reporting on exceptions out of your sidekiq process, but if you want to monitor the process itself, you'll need to do it from (yes) another process.  God and Monit are good, easy, free ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use airbrake gem.

for more detail about airbrake gem click here: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake

and airbrake: https://airbrake.io/